# Check if today is a new day SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

How can I check if today is a new day?
How can I say when the app lunches or in background, whichever, if it's 8am of a new day then do some action...

`Date()` would only give me the current date.

I need this to do some resetting and possibly to send notification at a specific time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try something like this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
@State var lastDay: Date = Date()
@State var isToday = false
@State var selectedTime = 8  // 24 hour clock

var body: some View {
    Text("your main view")
        .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification)) { _ in
            // store the date whenever you go into background
            print("---> storing: \(Date())")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(Date(), forKey: "lastDay")
    }
    .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification)) { _ in
        // try to retrieve the date when you come back from background
         print("\n----> try retrieve lastDay")
        if let temDate = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "lastDay") {
            self.lastDay = temDate as! Date
            print("----> retrieved lastDay: \(self.lastDay)")
            if Calendar.current.isDate(Date(), inSameDayAs: self.lastDay) {
                self.isToday = true
                print("----> isToday: \(self.isToday)\n")
                // if it is 8 am or later do something
                if let thisHour = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour], from: Date()).hour {
                    if (thisHour >= self.selectedTime) {
                        print("----> it is 8am or later --> do something")
                        // self.doSomething()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

NotificationCenter is Apple internal message system. SwiftUI can listen for specific events, like when the App goes into the background. This is what this line does:

```
.onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification))
```

Now, this line:

```
 .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification))
```

listens for when you come back from the background, as mentioned in the comments.

There is no slowing down because of these onReceives.

What I have shown is an approach, you can add other .onReceive, such as:

```
.onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification)) { _ in

.onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.willTerminateNotification)) { _ in
```

These can be used for when you start the App, and when you quit the App.

Comment: Hi, I'm not to clear what this line does: `NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification` could you explain? Also what if the app instead of going  to the background is quit? Will it still save the UserDefaults?

Comment: Also is it ok to put so many `.onReceive`? wouldn't that slow it down?, why not put it in 1

Answer (score 1):

So this all should work to be able to tell if the date has changed.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var lastDateString = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "lastDateString") ?? String()
//stores lastDateString in memory for if the app closes

    @State var lastDate = Date()

    @State var currentDate = Date()
    @State var currentDateString = String()
    @State var differentDate = false;

    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1.0, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    //Creates a timer that goes every 1 second 

    func newDay() {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "d MM y"
//sets the format so it will be day month year

        if lastDateString == String() {
            lastDateString = formatter.string(from: lastDate)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(self.lastDateString, forKey: "lastDateString")
        } //sets initial value for lastDateString for first time app ever launches

        self.currentDate = Date()
        currentDateString = formatter.string(from: currentDate)
        //sets currentDateString for every time app launches
        if lastDateString != currentDateString {

            self.differentDate = true

            self.lastDate = Date()
            self.currentDate = Date()
            lastDateString = formatter.string(from: lastDate)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(self.lastDateString, forKey: "lastDateString")
            currentDateString = formatter.string(from: currentDate)
        } 
//checks if the date has changed and sets differentDate to true if it has

    }
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
        Text("Hello, World!")
            .onAppear(){ //used to run function when app launches

                self.newDay()
        }
        }
    .onReceive(self.timer) { _ in
        self.newDay()

    } //calls function newDay() every second from timer


    }
}
```

Hope this helps and sorry that this may not be the most concise, but hopefully it helps.

Comment: That's no really checking if today is 8am and is a new day, is it? I believe that's just checking with the time if past date is less than Date() -> current date. Not really the answer I'm looking for

Comment: This checks to see if there is a change in the date. So take for example when the user last launched the app or had the app open it was June 3, 2020 at 10 pm if they then opened it 3 hours later it would be June 4, 2020 and my code would be able to say that there was a change in date. This is the goal right or are you trying to see if at least 24 hours have past?

Comment: No, the goal is not to see if the date has changed, it is to see if today is a whole new day than yesterday, let’s say today at 8am. Not checking constantly if Date() > previous date

Comment: Okay yeah then that is exactly what my code does. It does this by having formatter only include day, month, and year so that if it is still the same day then it does not set differentDate to true.

Comment: `if lastDateString != currentDateString` that's all you are doing there. By the way as a suggestion, if you use actual Date type you can achieve the same with like 4 lines of code. Your code would also become true at today 3pm, since it checks if lastDateString != currentDateString. That's not what I want

Comment: So you are wanting to detect if the date has changed correct? So if the user launched the app for the first time and it was 2pm on January 1, 2020 and then later that day say it was 4 pm on January 1, 2020 they open the app again then you want there to be no effect because there has not been a date change correct? But then say they opened it at 1 am on January 2, 2020 then it would detect there has been a date change and set differentDate to true correct? This is the intended functionality right?

Comment: Yes, that's the intended functionality. Right now your code checks fo the date is different from before at anytime

Comment: No my code actual does the exact thing that the intended functionality is. My code does nothing if there is a change in time just so long as it’s the same day, but when the day changes it returns differentDate as true.

Comment: I've been working for a long time today and I'm really tired, maybe I can't see it. Where do you check if Date() > pastDay?

Comment: When I do if lastDateString != currentDateString and this works because both of them are in the format d MM y (day month year) so for my area this would be 3 06 2020. So say I open the app today this would run newDay because of onAppear then lastDateString is set to "3 06 2020" because of if lastDateString == String() and then currentDateString is set to 3 06 2020 this would cause lastDateString and currentDateString to be the same and so the if statement fails. Then say tomorrow I open the app then currentDate becomes 4 06 2020 and then the if statement passes and self.differentDate = true

Comment: Oh... I skipped the formatting of the Date() , that's what you are trying to tell me... I see now. The question is, what if I wanted it for a specific time, like 8am. So at 8am of a new day which was the original question

Answer (score 0):

```swift
    if Calendar.current.isDate(lastVisit as! Date, inSameDayAs: Date()) {
      print("Same day")
    } else {
      print("New day")
    }
```